# How can I insert a row and return * with plpgsql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

This my first time messing with plpgsql and I have the following:

```
create or replace function create_marker(title text, description text, latitude decimal, longitude decimal) 
returns record
language plpgsql
as $$
declare 
  res record;
begin
  INSERT INTO markers (
    title,
    description,
    latitude,
    longitude,
    geometry
  ) VALUES 
  ('marker 1', 'this is marker1 1 description', 10, -100, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(10, -100), 4326))
  RETURNING * into res;
end;
$$;
```

but I get an error:

`a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"`

How can I fix this?

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM create_marker(...)
```

Comment: You need to specify `OUT` parameters for functions that returns `RECORD` type. Or just use `markers` instead of `record`

Comment: can you please explain what you mean by "or just use markers instead of record" sorry today is my first day with plpgsql..

Comment: Why are you using plpgsql at all? Make that a `LANGUAGE SQL` function.

Comment: In your code replace `record` by `markers`. And don't forget about `return res;` at the end of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with a the `RETURNING` clause of a [cte](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) :

```
create or replace function create_marker(title text, description text, latitude decimal, longitude decimal) 
returns record
language sql
as $$
WITH list AS
(
  INSERT INTO markers (
    title,
    description,
    latitude,
    longitude,
    geometry
  ) VALUES 
  ('marker 1', 'this is marker1 1 description', 10, -100, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(10, -100), 4326))
  RETURNING *
)
SELECT *
  FROM list ;
$$
```